# Sharepoint 2010 Visual Web Part - The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I`m using **VS 2013 ULTIMATE** but project is created in 2010 version because I have got old Sharepoint 2010. When I create new project I have got problem with 'InitializeControl'. **Do you know how can I fix problem with 'InitializeControl'?**

[image]

Warning 1

> The custom tool 'SharePointWebPartCodeGenerator' failed.  The local
>   SharePoint server is not available. Check that the server is running
>   and connected to the SharePoint farm. You may try re-running the
>   custom tool by right-clicking on the file in the Solution Explorer and
>   choosing Run Custom Tool.

Error 2

> The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context

I check this but does not help ->

http://big.info/2013/08/the-name-initializecontrol-does-not.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is good example http://samer-othman.blogspot.pt/2013/03/how-to-fix-error-name-initializecontrol.html but it's show longer way.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the g.cs file was missing and I have then create a new control on ascx page. I have added asp button control and add onclick event and I found that g.cs file has been created automatically and it is running now.

This is for Sand box solution as well as for On premise solution.

Answer (score 2):

The file doesn't get generated if the connection to the SharePoint environment wasn't successful.
Check the "Site URL" and "Server Connection" under project properties,
then right click on your *.ascx and click "Run Custom Tool".

Answer (score 1):

In my case it solved by adding the setting for hosts file like

127.0.0.1 mysite.domain.com

Comment: I mean the deploy URL

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Visual studio 2015 and SharePoint 2016:
 1. Give rights to access the config db to your user
 2. Right click .ascx file and select "Run Custom Tool"

Maurizio